# Factoring into two small factors modulo a constant

Tags: number-theory, algorithms, modular-arithmetic

Given a modulus $N$ and an integer $k \in [0, N)$ I'd like to "factor" $k$ into two values $a$ and $b$ both in $[0, N^{1/2 + \epsilon})$. I put quotes around "factor", because multiplying $a$ and $b$ together only needs to give $k$ when working modulo $N$.

Is it possible to efficiently find such values for any $k$ and $N$? Are they even guaranteed to exist?

One indicator that it might be easy to find these values is that the extended euclidean algorithm *nearly* does the trick. Amongst the numbers produced during intermediate states of the algorithm, you can find values $a$ and $b$ of size roughly $\sqrt{N}$ satisfying $a \cdot b^{-1} \equiv k \pmod{N}$, where $b^{-1}$ is the multiplicative inverse of $b$ modulo $N$ [[1](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0601097)]. But I don't want a small value of $b$ whose inverse is part of the "factorization", I want $b$ itself to be the factor.

Comment: What are the dependencies between $N, k, \epsilon$?

Comment: @MeesdeVries $N$ can be any positive integer. $k$ is a positive integer less than $N$. The $1/2 + \epsilon$ term is just shorthand for "it can be more than 0.5, but the goal is to try to keep it small"; there's no explicit dependence intended. You could substitute $2/3$ or $1/2 + o(1)$ I suppose.